# Why do we use std::function in C++ rather than the original C function pointer?

Tags: c++, c++11, function-pointers

What is the advantage of `std::function<T1(T2)>` over the original `T1 (*)(T2)`?

Comment: It's more versatile, but also slower. You can't compare `::std::function` instances and it allocates from the heap.

Comment: @user1095108:  It _may_ allocate from the heap.  Just like the "small `string` optimization," an implementation may use a "small `function` optimization."

Comment: `may`... a vain hope sometimes.

Comment: There might also be a disadvantage.

Answer (score 38, accepted):

`std::function` can hold more than function pointers, namely *functors*.

```
#include <functional>

void foo(double){}

struct foo_functor{
  void operator()(float) const{}
};

int main(){
  std::function<void(int)> f1(foo), f2((foo_functor()));
  f1(5);
  f2(6);
}
```

[Live example on Ideone.](http://ideone.com/qzbeF)

As the example shows, you also don't need the exact same signature, as long as they are *compatible* (i.e., the parameter type of `std::function` can be passed to the contained function / functor).

Comment: Also, with `std::bind` it is possible to create delegates (i.e. encapsulate a member function pointer with an object) and store them in an std::function, without any difference in handling after creation. This is something that function pointers alone are not capable of.

Comment: @fish: Well, what `std::bind` returns is a functor, so I wouldn't really special-case that. What can be seen as special is that you can just pass a member function pointer and the `std::function` will make it callable like `f(object, param);`. [Example on Ideone](http://ideone.com/haRtx)

Comment: Another thing is (arguably) easier declarations. Function pointer declarations are a little hard follow due to their C heritage of *"declaration reflecting usage"*-rule. `std::function` objects have a declaration that looks more like a function declaration. (sorry I really should make an edit, but I see that the post is still being updated frequently at this moment. feel free to merge in these).

Comment: yeah, well of course it does. I think it is worth mentioning because delegates are a common pattern in many languages and this is what makes it possible to fluidly replicate them in C++.

Comment: As it is, the program compiles but doesn't do anything. Can I suggest to `cout` the argument in both the function and the functor? And I'd also add a call using a non-integer argument, like `f1(4.7);`. This would show the effect of storing a function accepting a `double` into an `std::function` accepting an `int` parameter. I would also include the output into the answer. I've already prepared the modified code [on Ideone](https://ideone.com/PD9rwW). I can edit your answer myself, if you agree, but I'll do it only with your permission.

Answer (score 17):

`std::function` can hold function objects (including lambdas), as well as function pointers with the correct signature.  So it is more versatile.

Comment: Side question: I'm assuming the lambdas are called virtually, right?

Comment: @Mehrdad: What is your definition of *called virtually*?

Comment: @DavidRodríguez-dribeas: An indirect call, i.e. like a `virtual` function.

Comment: How is a `virtual` function indirect?

Comment: @Mehrdad: It can do that, it could also use a `void*` + a function pointer to a templated function.

Comment: @Mehrdad: `std::function<>` needs to add an indirection to perform the type erasure, so yes, there is one extra level of indirection con calling a lambda through `std::function` (well, calling a lambda or any other thing through `std::function`)

Comment: I thought that `virtual` just meant that it was inheritable?

Comment: And you can `std::bind` it like you're Lady Heather.

Comment: @anthropomorphic: No, `virtual` means it is *overridable* in derived classes.

Answer (score 11):

Apart from the cleaner look and a more descriptive syntax, `std::function` can store any *callable* object:

- functions
- lambda expressions
- bind expressions
- functors

Not to mention that storing, copying, and binding objects to member functions is much easier and more intuitive.

Comment: Bind expressions simply return functors, so having both functors and bind expressions listed is redundant.