# Advantages of using std::function

Tags: c++, c++11, c++14

Dear stackoverflow users.

I tried to find the advantages of [`std::function`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/functional/function), and why I should use it instead of functors or pointers to function. Sadly I did not find a satisfying answer.

That is why I will much appreciate if you would tell me what are advantages of `std::function`, and when should I use it. Hope that my question will help others as well.

Comment: Good explanation is [The importance of std::function](https://probablydance.com/2012/12/16/the-importance-of-stdfunction/). Related articles: [Why do we use std::function...](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11352936/why-do-we-use-stdfunction-in-c-rather-than-the-original-c-function-pointer) and [Should I use std::function...](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25848690/should-i-use-stdfunction-or-a-function-pointer-in-c).

Answer (score 8, accepted):

`std::function` implements a technique called *type-erasure* because of which you can **store** *any* callable entity in `std::function`, be it functors, member functions, or free functions — you can even *store* *member-data* as well which seems counter intuitive!

Here is one example, which cannot be done without `std::function` (or *type-erasure*):

```
std::vector<std::function<void()>>  funs;
for(int i = 0; i < 10; ++i)
  funs.push_back([i] { std::cout << i < std::endl; });

for(auto const & f: funs)
   f();
```

Here is another example which stores *member-data*:

```
struct person
{ 
    std::string name;
};

int main()
{
    std::vector<person> people {
      {"Bjarne"},
      {"Alex"}
    };

    std::function<std::string(person const&)> name (&person::name);

    for(auto const & p : people)
       std::cout << name(p) << std::endl;
}
```

Output ([demo](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/view?id=6532850a32dff153)):

```
Bjarne
Alex
```

Hope that helps.

Comment: `function<string(person const&)> name (&person::name);` - You are fooling the compiler by its own powers!

Comment: @Ajay could you elaborate ?

Answer (score 1):

The point of `std::function` is to provide type erasure over a generic callable object with some given prototype. You use it when you want your function/your class/whatever to receive some generic callable object with a certain signature (be it a function pointer, a functor or a lambda) without having to make everything template over the type of such callable.

Also, there are situations where even making everything template wouldn't help; think about having a vector of heterogeneous "stuff" that can be called, for example a signal-like object. Without this kind of type erasure it is essentially impossible.